# Extract multiple value from JSON response TERADATA

Tags: json, teradata

I'm trying to get multiple values from a JSON response using TERADATA SQL Engine.

**input:**

```
{"barrings": [{"0": True,"1": false,"5": True,"barring": "BARALL"}]}.
```

**Desired output:**

| id | barring | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1546075 | 0 | true |
| 1546075 | 1 | false |
| 1546075 | 5 | true |

I tried to get this using the TERADATA JSON functions but it didn't give me what I wanted.

If anyone can help me, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Without seeing more of the source and what you are trying (that isn't giving you the desired output) it's hard to be sure. But the structure of your JSON doesn't seem to support what you are trying to do. You may need to extract the value of "barrings" as a string and parse it using something like STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE,  REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE or CSVLD

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I used STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE and it gave me what I was looking for. Thank you so much.